# Command line argument passing

Tags: c, command-line

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int number, char arg[])
{
    int i;

    printf("%d\n",number);

    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
        printf("%c",arg[i]);
    printf("\n");   

    return 0;
}
```

I am running it in ubuntu terminal and running it by typing "./a.out".I expected the output to be "./a.out" but instead some garbage value is getting printed . Please explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your signature for `main()` is wrong:

```
int main(int number, char arg[])
```

should be:

```
int main(int number, char *arg[])
```

Then access it like a 2d array while printing, like:

```
for(i=0;i<strlen(argv[0]);i++)
    printf("%c",arg[0][i]);
```

Or just print the string at index 0:

```
printf("%s",arg[0]);
```

Comment: Not only that, unless arg is certain to have enough values such that arg[7] is a valid array access, the code is essentially pulling a random value from memory, no?

Comment: @mcl That's a very valid point. Since, OP seems to want to print using chars, I changed it to using `strlen` as the strings are guaranteed to have null termination.

Comment: @KingsIndian you should also optimize out the `strlen(argv[0])` part to a variable - calling strlen on every single operation is not needed, and not every compiler may be able to realize that fact.

Comment: @H2CO3 I agree, but this is really just to print one string `arg[0]`. Hopefully, OP will learn other things over time ;-)

Comment: @KingsIndian I hope it really, me too, because what he has showed so far is less than valuable.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're missing the type of `argv`. The OS pre-parses the arguments for you (separates them by spaces), so you'll end up having an array of strings. You should write:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("%s ", argv[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

in order to get the whole command line invocation back.

P. s.: **you should really name the arguments of `main()` argc and argv.** It's idiomatic and not doing so is *strange.*

Answer (score 0):

The signature of `main` is `int main (int argc, char* argv[])` - i.e. `argv` is an array of strings, not an array of chars.

Answer (score 0):

the main function, by convention takes an int as first parameter (this is ok in your code), but the second parameter has to be a pointer on an array of chars (`char *argv[]`).

This has to be so because when your program is called, it has its paremeter whithin this array.
If you call `./a.out foo bar`, the array will be

```
arg[0] = "./a.out"
arg[1] = "foo"
arg[2] = "bar"
```

and the integer will contain 3, the number of arguments given to your program.

If you wanted to print the number of argument given to your program and its arguments, you would need to transform your code to this

```
int main(int number, char *arg[]) // the right main prototype
{
    int i;

    printf("%d\n",number);

    for(i=0;i<number;i++) // from i = 0 to the number of parameters
        printf("%s\n",arg[i]); // print a string (%s)

    return 0;
}
```